# MySql AES-Decrypted Field empty

Tags: mysql, aes

I was trying to en- and decypt data with the corresponding MySQL-functions.
This is what I did:

```
INSERT INTO dbsec.tbl_credent (U_Password) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('secretText', SHA2('pwd123',512)));
```

the Primary-Key (id) was 6. So I used

```
SELECT dbsec.tbl_credent.U_Password FROM dbsec.tbl_credent WHERE dbsec.tbl_credent.id = '6';
```

I got something like this:

```
Ž4•ý/2Ÿ½üyÙ¤Ý'
```

So encryption seems to work so far.
When I start the following query:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(dbsec.tbl_credent.U_Password, 'pwd123') FROM dbsec.tbl_credent WHERE dbsec.tbl_credent.id = '6';
```

Result is *NULL*

I used hashing for the password so I tried

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(dbsec.tbl_credent.U_Password, SHA2('pwd123',512)) FROM dbsec.tbl_credent WHERE dbsec.tbl_credent.id = '6';
```

Result is *73656372657454657874*

As all this didn't work I tested this directly:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('secretText', SHA2('pwd123',512)), 'pwd123');
```

Again the Result was *NULL* and

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('secretText', 'pwd123'), 'pwd123');
```

returned *73656372657454657874* again.

What do I have to do to get back the 'secretText' I have encrypted?
The Type of U_Password is *text* (latin1_swedish_ci), btw.

Comment: User passwords should not generally be encrypted. http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: And how does this work with MySQL? Besides, U_Password is just a name of a former version. I simply would like to encrypt the data within with AES.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with MySQL's AES\_DECRYPT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720599/problem-with-mysqls-aes-decrypt)